# Design a Student-Course-Teacher-Semester spreadsheet

Tags: database-design, class-design

Recently I was asked to design for curriculum application (in Java) model dealing with Student/Teacher/Semester/Course entities. It is something like spreadsheet design problem.

The condition was: a student can enroll for a course, taught by some teacher, for a semester occurring at a particular time, say at semester-2.

A student may have multiple courses, taught by multiple teachers (each teacher teaches a specific course) at multiple time (each course occurs at an unique semester).
Thus the combination of student + course + teacher+ semester is unique.

What will be a smarter design?

I initially started with a class having  student id and a Map where the map has 'key' value set to Course-id and 'value' set to another class, say TeacherSemester.
The TeacherSemesterclass contains the TeacherId and SemesterId values.

But this does not seem to be a scalable solution. 
Can anyone suggest a better design?
Any discussion will be helpful.

Thaks

Comment: I think you would be better served trying it out yourself and muddle on through.  You may not be happy with your first attempt, but you'll learn a lot more about it than simply asking SO what we think.  For example, if there's something about your first iteration you don't like, you will know very intimately why it was a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Teacher and Student are roles, they aren't classes.

```
class Person
{
    string Name
}
class Course
{
    List<Person> enrolledStudents
    List<Person> teachers
    Semester semester
    CourseTime time
}
class Application
{
    List<Course> courses
    List<Person> persons
    List<Semesters> semester
    List<CourseTime> courseTimes
}
```